# add non "type library" dll as reference to VS C++ 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, dll

I just received a request from colleague to work out why a specific dll cannot be added as a reference in Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM with MS .Net Framework Version 3.5 SP1.

The language used is Visual C++ 2008, I have never done anything in this language, although I've done a bit in C# before...

Please check the following two error messages, first one came from my laptop, the second from my colleague's:
[image: my error message]

[image: another error message]

From my Google research I am afraid the target dll is:

- NOT a type library. Confirmed by running the tlbimp utility:

  ```
  tlbimp C:\test\tm1api.dll

  ......

  error TI0000 : The input file 'C:\test\tm1api.dll' is not a valid type library
  ```

  What does this mean, anything to convert it to a type library?
- NOT a .NET assembly or a registered ActiveX Control. The dll was not programmed in VS I am   afraid. But how could I verify this?

Basically I am confused, because two VS 2008 show different error messages, is this issue specific to VS 2008 only? Or is there a general solution in VS for this sort of thing?

Many thanks to the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you've probably got just a regular old dll.  use the [dllimport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to access its methods.  Be aware that there are usually all kinds of data marshalling issues when interacting with a C++ dll, like instead of int you might need to use short, and IntPtr instead of arrays...stuff like that.